# How to find the mean number of positive consecutive values for each factor/level?

Tags: r

I am working with weather data and for each year I want to find the mean and standard deviation (SD) of the number of consecutive days that have a temperature greater than 0.

I've tried `group_by` using `sequence`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the need to calculate the mean (or SD) of consecutive days WITH a positive temperature.

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
season<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
temp<-c(4,3,0,2,-1,2,2,2,-2,1,0,1,0,1,0)

df<-cbind(season,temp)
```

I want a table that lists the seasons with the mean and the SD of the number of consecutive positive temperatures like this:

[image: this].

For example, in season 1, the first 2 days are above 0 and the 4th day is above 0, so the mean=(2+1)/2.

```
     season consec_positive_mean consec_positive_SD
[1,]      1                  1.5                0.5
[2,]      2                  2.0                0.3
[3,]      3                  1.0                0.0
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please check your expected output.  It is not reflecting the input consecutive valuess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create first small functions :

```
ConsecMean <- function(x) { 
    x <- ifelse(x > 0, 0, 1) 
    cs <- cumsum(x) 
    cs <- cs[x == 0] 
    mean <- mean(table(cs)) 
    return(mean) 
    } 
ConsecSD <- function(x) { 
    x <- ifelse(x > 0, 0, 1) 
    cs <- cumsum(x) 
    cs <- cs[x == 0] 
    sd <- sd(table(cs)) 
    return(sd) 
    }
```

Then apply it with `group_by` from dplyr :

```
df %>% 
    group_by(season) %>% 
    summarise(mean = ConsecMean(temp), sd = ConsecSD(temp))
```

output :

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 3
  season  mean    sd
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1   1.5 0.707
2      2   2   1.41 
3      3   1   0
```

However, I am not sure how to calculate SD in your case

Answer (score 1):

An option would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp  := rleid(temp > 0)][temp > 0, .N, 
    .(season, grp)][, .(Mean = mean(N), SD = sd(N)), season]
#.  season Mean        SD
#1:      1  1.5 0.7071068
#2:      2  2.0 1.4142136
#3:      3  1.0 0.0000000
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(season, temp)
```

Comment: When I try this on my data, I receive this error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Alyssa.r. If it is based on the example you showed, I am not getting the error